# Time Complexity for alphabetical order using skip list

Tags: data-structures, skip-lists

What will be time Complexity for Displaying data in alphabetical order using skip-list ?
and what time complexity will be for skip list if we implement using quad node ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that you have the input that contains *N* elements. Firstly you have to construct a skip-list. The complexity of a single insert operation is *[O(log N)](https://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~montanar/teaching/dsa/skiplists-handout.pdf)* in average so the complexity of inserting N elements would be *O(N * log N)*. When the skip-list is constructed then elements within this list are sorted. So in order to enumerate them you only need to visit each element what is *O(N)*.

It is worth saying that the skip-list is based on randomness. It means that *O(log N)* complexity of a single insert operation is not guaranteed. The worst case complexity is *[O(N)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)*, It means that in the worst case the complexity of inserting N elements into the skip-list would be *O(N^2)*.